# RxJS return error after retryWhen is completed

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I would like to return error after `retryWhen` is finished. Here is code example:

```js
const httpGet = (d, res) => {
  return rxjs.of(res).pipe(rxjs.operators.delay(d));
};

const repeat = () => {
  return httpGet(1000, false).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(() => console.log("Response from repeat")),
    rxjs.operators.flatMap(res => {
      if (res === false) {
        // Throw error due to invalid response
        return rxjs.throwError("Invalid response inside repeat");
      }

      return rxjs.of(res);
    }),
    rxjs.operators.retryWhen(err => {
      // Retry same httpGet call due to invalid response
      return err.pipe(
        rxjs.operators.flatMap(e => {
          // Delay execution of next httpGet call
          return rxjs.timer(1000);
        }),
        // Retry httpGet call only 3 times
        rxjs.operators.take(3)
      );
    })
  );
};

const execute = () => {
  return httpGet(1000, false).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(() => console.log("Response from execute")),
    rxjs.operators.switchMap(res => {
      // If res is false wait 1sec and execute repeat()
      if (res === false) {
        return rxjs.timer(1000).pipe(rxjs.operators.concatMapTo(repeat()));
      }

      return rxjs.of(res);
    })
  );
};

// Start executing
execute().subscribe(
  r => console.log("Response:", r),
  err => console.error("Error:", err),
  () => console.log("Completed")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

This is the current output:

```
Response from execute
Response from repeat
Response from repeat
Response from repeat
Completed
```

And I would like to obtain the following output:

```
Response from execute
Response from repeat
Response from repeat
Response from repeat
Error: Some message
```

So I need to throw error in some place after repeat calls has finished without valid response.

Comment: I allowed myself to provide a [mcve] of your issue with a snippet, and I removed the Angular tag (since it's only related to RxJS even though you use Angular). If you feel this is unfair, just tell me, I'll rollback the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw at the last execution

```
   rxjs.operators.retryWhen(err => {
      let count=0;
      // Retry same httpGet call due to invalid response
      return err.pipe(
        rxjs.operators.flatMap(e => {
          ++count;
          console.log(count)
          // Delay execution of next httpGet call
          if(count===3) return rxjs.throwError(e);
          return rxjs.timer(1000);
        }),
        // Retry httpGet call only 3 times
        rxjs.operators.take(3)
      );
    })
  );
```

Comment: This soluction works pretty well. Is there some more accurate / elegant version of this solution ?

Comment: Attach scan operator in err.pipe to store count

Comment: There is also a count() operator u can use